# fwrite PNG creates file with zero bytes

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, png, fwrite

I have an 'export' custom script that outputs a bunch of highcharts charts in various formats, including .xls, .png and .PDF. The script works perfectly on my personal laptop, however PNG export fails when I try to run it on my client's company cpu / network.

I am pretty sure this is not a permissions issue. The script creates the PNG files and deletes them as appropriate, and I can see the files being added to the writable folder and then being deleted. It's just that the files are all 0kb. When the script is finished, the file that is supposed to combine all PNGs is also 0kb.

I am therefore thinking this is an issue with the fwrite function, but am confused as to why it is working on my laptop but not on client cpu. Could this be a browser issue? They use IE 9. Here is the relevant code:

```
    <?php

/**
 * 
 */
class actions_exportcsv {



    private static function hcexport($post_string) { //echo $post_string; die;
        // curl init
        $ch = curl_init("http://export.highcharts.com/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
//            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
//                "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------26008479621944;",
//                "Content-Length: ".  strlen($post_string).";",
//            )
        ));
        // curl exec
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        //set data to be posted
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch);
        //print_r($resultStatus);  
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

}

?>
```

Hope you can help me and shed some light on what is going on... Have a great day!

EDIT: Please find below the relevant bits of the error log:

```
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\xataface\Dataface\Application.php on line 576
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ENV in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\actions\exportcsv.php on line 177
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:39 Europe/Berlin] C:/xampp/htdocs/Raptor/18.png
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:43 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ENV in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\actions\exportcsv.php on line 177
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:43 Europe/Berlin] C:/xampp/htdocs/Raptor/22.png
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  getimagesize(): Read error! in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\actions\exportcsv.php on line 225
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  getimagesize(): Read error! in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\actions\exportcsv.php on line 226
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\actions\exportcsv.php on line 230
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefrompng(): '18.png' is not a valid PNG file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\actions\exportcsv.php on line 233
[19-Mar-2014 01:57:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefrompng(): '18.png' is not a valid PNG file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raptor\actions\exportcsv.php on line 234
```

Comment: Could you `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top, and check your error log (or maybe the source of your page if your server is not set to visually log errors)? Also make sure that there isn't some kind of debug mode in the highcharts library that is preventing it from logging errors. It sounds like perhaps your server is missing a dependency and the highcharts `hcexport` command is returning `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your help teh1. I have uploaded the log in the section above. I hope this will give you a better idea of what is going on...

Comment: Have you tried to compare chmod on the directions and check if fwrite is allowed on the client's server?

Comment: Hello Sebastian! Chmod is for Linux, right? I am using Apache on windows 7. If you are asking whether Apache has the right permissions then yes, it definitely does -I added myself as the user, and can see PNG files being written (and deleted) in the drive as requested by the script above ... it's just that those files are empty (0kb)...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ask the server for the right folder. Also make sure the folder that has the images are readable and writeable by the server.

It is not a browser problem as you running backend code in the php. Do you run same php version on both computers? Try check if they are configured the same way, might be a php/apache module that is not loaded.

Comment: Hello Medda. What PHP/Apache modules should be loaded for this? I am pretty sure it isn't a permissions issue as I can see the files being created / deleted in the folder when I run the script.

Comment: Hi Noobster, yes you are right. I was just saying incase you would have loaded some module on one machine and forgot on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log you posted, here are the immediate problems I can see. Fix them and if it still doesn't work, post the log and I will add to my answer:

ENV is not defined. ENV seems to be the path to your `xampp` folder, but it is undefined here, which means it's possible that you are not pointing to the right file. Then again, maybe you are since it's creating an empty file.

You are not posting all your code. Please post all the code that is at the lines mentioned in the log and I will modify my answer:

177, 225, 226, 230, 233, 234

It would be best if you just posted the entire function or at least some meaningful context for line 177, and the same for 226 and 230-234.

It's clear that the image is not actually being created, so `false`, or nothing at all as PHP treats it, is being written to the file. Do the above and I can answer better.

Comment: Hello, I have posted the entire code as requested. I am guessing the issue is the following line: `fwrite($fp, self::hcexport('filename=' . $v . "&type=image/png&width=800&svg=" . $post_content[$k]));` For some reason it looks like the images are not being created by the exporting server.